# Displaying image from website in picture box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I am facing a problem in showing an image from a web site in picture box, because the website uses this code for image:

```
<img src="showImage" id="secimage" style="border:none;height: 40px" />
```

I created a web browser in Visual Basic to open the site. I want to show this specific image in a picture box. My current code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.mypicsite.com")
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

        ***this is the picture fox in which i have to show a image from
        WebBrowser1(www.mypicsite.com)
        My pic site havve image with tag-
            <img src="showImage" id="secimage" style="border:none;height: 40px" />
        please help me.***

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. Replace your URL in there.

```
PictureBox1.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("YOUR_IMAGE_URL")))
```

Comment: Thats the actual problem. the image on website is not by url its as a src. The image src is.

Comment: <img src="showImage" id="secimage" style="border:none;height: 40px" />

Comment: is there is any way to show image in picturebox using GetElementsbyTagname ("img") the get the image by id ("secimage") and then show in picturebox

Comment: Actually for this you will have to first fet html of page by url then find the image tag by ID then access its src attribute then convert it to a url using domain name and then download image. Use divide and rule approach and implement steps 1 by 1.

Comment: PLZ HELP ME I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS. M NEWBIE